# Eclipse refer to image

Tags: java, eclipse, resources

So i am new to Java and this will probaly the easiest question you will ever see, still I can not find the anser on the internet.

I want to set the icon of my program, This code does works:
`frame.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("MYPROBLEM"));`

Yet i can not get the path correct at the MYPROBLEM section. This is my structure:

> Projectname
>
> -src
>
> --default package
>
> ---myfunctions
>
> --test <----a map
>
> ---icon.png

Whenever i replace MYPROBLEM with src/test/icon.png it does work. however when i export my application as jar the default Java icon shows up. Replacing MYPROBLEM with something like test/icon.png does also not works.

I do appologise for my English. Bear with me because I am a newbie ;)

Comment: I thought that these kind of resources need to be in the resources  folder (don't use eclipse, but see this question all the time)

Comment: 'frame.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("MYPROBLEM.png"));'

Comment: the .png part is not the problem. and i dont know where to create the resources folder. there is no by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will load an image from the classpath.

```
Image image = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("MYPROBLEM")).getImage();
frame.setIconImage(image);
```

Comment: placed the icon.png in the src folder. getImage("icon.png") did not work.

Answer (score 0):

for some reason sometimes it does not work but what you can do is to add the full path of the location of the image.  here is an example

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Image;

import java.awt.Toolkit;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import java.awt.Toolkit;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class JFrameIcon {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        frame.setSize(300, 150);

        frame.setTitle("tutorialData.com");

        frame.setResizable(false);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);

        frame.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("C:\\Users\\Sirnurpc\\Desktop\\icon.png"));

        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

reference [seticon](http://tutorialdata.com/example/swing/seticontojframe.html)

In your case if you are using Netbeans  then the location would be

**C:\Users\yourloginname\Documents\NetBeansProjects\yourproject\imagename.png**

And for Eclipse which I am guessing you are using would be something like this

**C:\Users\yourlogingname\workspace\yourproject\imagename.png**

Comment: this is not what i am looking for. the .jar will also distributed to other computers. therefore a "static" path wont work.

Comment: Are you using Default package ?

Comment: i am using eclipse. i dont know what default package means but its a small project and i did not add anything weird to it. i just choosed for a standard java project.